# How to get the QLayouts to expand properly?

Tags: c++, qt, layout, widget, qwebview

My structure is as follows:

```
QWidget
    -QHBoxLayout
         -QLabel
         -QVBoxLayout
              -QLabel
              -QWebView
```

I want the HBoxLayout to fill the width however large the container may be but go no more or less. However, I want the QVBoxLayout to expand to accommodate the size of its contents in the vertical direction.

```
+-------------+------------------------------+
| FixedTitle: | Expanding to Width Title     +
|             |------------------------------+
|             |                              +
|             | this is a test which wraps to+
|             | the next line                +
|             |                              +
|             |                              +
|             |                              +
|             | bla bla bla                  +
|             |                              +
|             |                              +
|             |                              +
|             | there are no vertical scroll +
|             | bars here                    +
+-------------+------------------------------+
```

In this example, FixedTitle's width is however big it needs to be, but does not resize ever. Expanding to Width Title fills up the remaining horizontal space.

So far, I have:

```
this->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout;
this->setLayout(layout);

layout->addWidget(new QLabel(QString("FixedTitle")), 0, Qt::AlignTop);

QVBoxLayout *v_layout = new QVBoxLayout;
v_layout->setSizeConstraint(QLayout::SetNoConstraint);
layout->addLayout(v_layout);

v_layout ->addWidget(new QLabel(QString("Expanding to Width Title")), 1, Qt::AlignTop | Qt::AlignLeft);

QWebView *view = new QWebView();

QTextEdit text;
text.setPlainText(QSString("\nthis is a test which wraps to the next line\n\n\nbla bla bla\n\n\nthere are no vertical scroll bars here"));
view->setHtml(text.toHtml());

int width = view->page()->mainFrame()->contentsSize().width();
int height = view->page()->mainFrame()->contentsSize().height();
view->page()->setViewportSize(QSize(width, height));
view->resize(width, height);
view->setFixedSize(width, height);

v_layout->addWidget(view);
```

There are two problems with this: 1. It ignores the width of the container and 2. It still doesnt get the height of the QWebView correct.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Could you explain your sizing goal a bit more clearly? First, what sizing do you want to happen between the label and the layout in the first horizontal layout? Second, what relationship of sizing do you want between the label (textedit?) and webview in the vertical layout? Are you trying to make the webview never have horizontal scroll bars?

Comment: @jdi I added a little image, does that help?

Comment: Yes thanks. Also whats the deal with the QTextEdit. You mentioned two QLabels.

Comment: @jdi I updated it to match the image better. The QTextEdit is there just to convert text to an html page.

Comment: Last question. Between the QTextEdit and the QWebView, how to you want them both to size related to the contents? I am clear on the other components now. But when should vertical bars become visible?

Comment: @jdi The QTextEdit is never added to the Layout, it is just to convert the string to html. The QWebView should never display vertical scroll bars as the widget should expand to accommodate its size. Is that clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my take on an answer... and forgive me but its written in PyQt.

I feel that your shouldn't be thinking so much about resizing the containing widget to the contents of the QWebView, but rather just have the size policy set to expanding, turn off the scrollbars, and defer sizing to whatever layout this container is added to. It makes no sense to try and manually resize it.

```py
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWebKit

class WebWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(WebWidget, self).__init__()

        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)

        title = QtGui.QLabel("FixedTitle:")
        # title.setText("A much larger fixed title")

        title.setSizePolicy(
            QtGui.QSizePolicy.Preferred, 
            QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)

        layout.addWidget(title, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

        v_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(v_layout)

        expandingTitle = QtGui.QLabel("Expanding to Width Title")
        expandingTitle.setSizePolicy(
            QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, 
            QtGui.QSizePolicy.Fixed)

        v_layout.addWidget(expandingTitle)

        text = QtGui.QTextEdit()

        view = QtWebKit.QWebView()
        view.setSizePolicy(
            QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, 
            QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        view.page().mainFrame().setScrollBarPolicy(
            QtCore.Qt.Vertical, 
            QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff )

        view.page().mainFrame().setScrollBarPolicy(
            QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 
            QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff )

        v_layout.addWidget(view, 1)

        text.setPlainText("""
            this is a test which wraps to the next line\n\n\n
            bla bla bla\n\n\nthere are no vertical scroll bars here
            """)
        view.setHtml(text.toHtml())

        v_layout.addStretch()

        self.view = view
        view.page().mainFrame().contentsSizeChanged.connect(self.updateWebSize)

    def updateWebSize(self, size=None):
        if size is None:
            size = self.view.page().mainFrame().contentsSize()
        self.view.setFixedSize(size)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super(WebWidget, self).resizeEvent(event)
        self.updateWebSize()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication([])

    w = QtGui.QScrollArea()
    w.resize(800,600)

    web = WebWidget()
    w.setWidget(web)
    w.setWidgetResizable(True)

    w.show()

    app.exec_()
```

- The left title is set to preferred width and fixed height, so that it gets the width it needs but doesn't grow vertically.
- The expanding title gets an expanding width policy and a fixed height.
- The QWebView gets expanding policies in both directions, and its scrollbars turned off.

And for an example. I just created a QScrollArea and set the WebWidget into it, so that you can see the parent layout will allow the Web view to grow as big as it wants to, but will handle overflow with scrollbars.

Comment: the problem here is that the QWebView isnt made full size, you just hide the scroll bar. otherwise, its awesome! thanks!

Comment: But if its always expanding, isn't it as full size as it can get at all times?

Comment: yea, you would think, but thats not happening for me.

Comment: Is there a certain content source I can use to see exactly what you mean? I would love to solve the problem completely, but I seem to be missing what it means here.

Comment: I think I might understand. Just made an update. I have the resize event of the web widget constantly updating the size. Is that it? (Currently has a bit of a hiccup where you have to resize the window to see it start doing it )

Comment: now you got the correct height, but: `self.view.setFixedSize(self.view.page().mainFrame().contentsSize())` forces the width to be a specific size (greater than the size of the container), i.e. this causes horizontal scroll bars. Also, weirdly enough, the html page with less contents didnt shrink.

Comment: Yea I guess I don't get it. The webview itself never has scrollbars. It only sizes itself to the content and shows scrollbars on the parent widget. I gave it a shot! I dont get what should happen to the width. Should it clip if its bigger?

Comment: I found the problem: looking at QWebView's source you have: `QSize QWebView::sizeHint() const
{
    return QSize(800, 600); // ####...
}` meaning that the size hint isnt based on the actual size of the content. No, you're right the webview wont get the scroll bars, but I dont want the main scroll window to ever have horizontal scroll bars (vertical scroll bars on the qscrollarea is fine).